# requisição Fetch com ASP .Net Core 3.0

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, .net, fetch

Estou tentando substrituir os métodos Ajax pelo Fetch na aplicação, porém não consigo receber um objeto com o Fetch, fiz um pequeno objeto de teste para tentar receber, no Ajax, consigo passando parâmetro pelo Data

```
    public class ObjetoTeste
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }
    }
```

No meu controller, recebo da seguinte forma

```
    public JsonResult Teste(long s, ObjetoTeste obj)
    {
        return Json(obj);
    }
```

Com Ajax, recebo o objeto normalmente, já no Fetch, não consigo enviar nada, ele sempre recebe nulo no Controller, no Javascript, montei 2 métodos que recebem o mesmo objeto, idêntico, e ambos se comportam de forma diferente.

```
    var data = {
        s: 500,
        obj: {
            Nome: 'Nome',
            NomeFantasia: 'NomeFantasia'
        }
    }

    _private.Ajax = function () {
        console.log('Ajax')
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Teste",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

    _private.Fetch = function () {
        console.log('Fetch')
        fetch('/Home/Teste', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data,
        }).then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        })
    }
```

É apenas um trecho de exemplo, porém caso dê certo, irei implementar o método Fetch como padrão em minhas requisições.

Comment: o que tem no objeto `data`? essa vírgula a mais é desnecessária aqui: `body: data,`

Comment: data é o objeto que criei para enviar, como está código que postei, e mesmo sem a vírgula ele chega nulo no controller.

Comment: humm não tinha visto o objeto data... tentou especificar no header que é um `json`?, adicionando por exemplo isso antes do data: `headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },`

Comment: Consegui resolver parcialmente, não do jeito que gostaria, tive que trocar o parâmetro no Controller com a tag [FromBody], porém o s ainda tenho que passar como parâmetro na url,            
 fetch('/Home/Teste/?s=500', o que impossibilita caso queira passar vários objetos como parâmetros, não teria um jeito de usar o Fetch como se fosse o Ajax? Ou o Fetch ainda não substitui as funcionalidades do Ajax?

Comment: neste caso vc tem duas soluções para enviar um único objeto como `[FromBody`: juntar tudo numa mesma classe (`ObjetoTeste `  também ter o `long s`, ou juntar os dois numa terceira classe), ou então receber um objeto do tipo `JObject`, e só separar depois o `s` e o  `ObjetoTeste`. Se quiser posso responder com um exemplo

Comment: Esse funcionamento não atenderia, eu no caso iria alterar as requisições Ajax de um ERP, pensei que o funcionamento fosse parecido, seria mais para teste de performance do que necessidade real da troca, mas sinta-se a vontade para responder com o exemplo, irei marcar sua resposta como aceita, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @ChristianRibeiro Faça as duas requisições, pegue os payloads no console do browser e compare-os. Se não conseguir achar o problema, mostre os dois payloads na sua pergunta para que possamos ver qual a diferença entre eles.